# Angular JS: Using $scope.variable Across Controllers

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-scope

So, I've got a counter (`$scope.counter`) that I increment on `ng-click`. The problem I'm having is that I want to increment it from two different controllers, keeping the counter value in sync.

**controllerA.js**

```
.controller('controllerA', controllerA);
  function controllerA($scope) {
    $scope.counter = 0;

    function incrementCounter() { 
      $scope.counter = $scope.counter + 1;
    }
    ...
```

**controllerB.js**

```
.controller('controllerB', controllerB);
  function controllerB($scope) {
    $scope.counter = 0;

    function incrementCounter() { 
      $scope.counter = $scope.counter + 1;
    }
    ...
```

When I call the `incrementCounter()` on `'controllerA'` it updates the counter on `'controllerA'`, but not on `'controllerB'` and vice versa.

Is there a proper way to keep these in sync, no matter which controller I call the `incrementCounter()` function from?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Create a service that contains the counter variable and/or function and inject that service into both controllers

Comment: In these type of scenarios you might be tempted to use `$rootScope`, which is **not** good practice rather use service as suggested be @jbrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A service is a good way to share the counter variable. If you want to avoid watches to keep them in sync, make sure you define the variable as a property of an object on the service. You can set the value to null initially if you want to populate it with a `$http` callout as per your comment.

```
app.service('MyService', ['$http', function($http) {
  var service = {
    counter: {
      value: null
    },
    incrementCounter: incrementCounter,
    fetchTotal: fetchTotal
  }

  return service;

  function incrementCounter(){
    service.counter.value++;
  }

  function fetchTotal(url, p) {
    $http.get(url, { params: p })
      .then(function(response) {
        service.counter.value = response.data.meta.total;
      }, function(error) {
        console.log("error occurred");
    });
  }
}]);
```

Then assign the `counter` object as a property on `$scope` in your controllers, and call the service to do the `$http` callout:

```
app.controller('Controller1', function ($scope, MyService) {
  $scope.counter = MyService.counter;

  $scope.incrementCounter = function(){
    MyService.incrementCounter();
  }

  fetchTotal('/test', '');
});
```

Assigning the `counter` object as a property on `$scope` ensures that ensure two-way binding is intact in the view. You can use `ng-if` so you don't render anything until the `$http` call is complete and the counter is initialised.

```
<div ng-controller="Controller1">
  <div ng-if="counter.value">
    {{counter.value}}
    <span ng-click="incrementCounter()">increment</span>  
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheilak/vge1w86t/) with a mocked `$httpBackend`

Comment: What if I want to do a `$http.get` request to retrieve my counter total from an API. Like so: `fetchTotal: function(p) {
  return $http.get(url, { params: p })
    .then(function(response) {
      var total = response.data.meta.total;
      return total;
    }, function(error) {
      console.log("error occured");
    })
}`, how would be best to increment on that total variable?

Comment: Am I able to put my params in my controller in this example?

Comment: Yes, fiddle updated to show that. I'll update the answer too.

Comment: Fantastic answer! Thank you. Very helpful in helping me split up my code into a service.

Answer (score 1):

This is where services come in handy.

egghead.io has a nice video on this: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controllers

He talks a lot about ui-router as well, but it also shows how you can use a service.

**UPDATE**

If you want the value to update instantaniously in both controllers you can watch the service.

http://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/1swyy6re/2/

```
app.service('counterService', function() {
    this.counter = 0;
    this.addOne = function(){
        this.counter++;
    }
    this.getCounter = function(){
        return this.counter;
    }
});

//Controllers
app.controller("controller1",function($scope, counterService){
    $scope.counterService = counterService;
    $scope.$watch('counterService.getCounter()', function (newVal) {
      $scope.counter = newVal;
    });

    $scope.addOne = function(){
       counterService.addOne();
   }
})

app.controller("controller2",function($scope, counterService){
    //same internals as controller 1
})
```

In your views you can now have both controllers that will update simultaniously

```
<div ng-controller="controller1">
    counter value: {{counter}}
    <button ng-click="addOne()">add 1</button>
</div>

<div ng-controller="controller2">
    counter value: {{counter}}
    <button ng-click="addOne()">add 1</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It's kind of a similar example. I'm displaying two views on the same page though, each with their own controller. I've got a service setup which is providing each controller with the SAME counter number. However, when I do an ng-click on viewA (controller A), it only updates the counter inside view A and not the counter inside view B.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions.

1. using `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`.
2. Having a parent controller and define `$scope.counter = 0` in it, then in your child controllers(A,B) that are used in this parent just update the `$scope.counter` value.

Comment: But both of them are not recommended way. If service is used, code is more maintainable and testable. And, if complexity for counter increases in future, one can easily abstract its implementation from both the controllers

Answer (score 0):

You also can use the broadcast of events to update the value in other controller. [Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/N7CLISavTInQNq1Qyifn?p=preview) is how it can be done:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.counter = 0;
  $scope.incrementCounter = function() {
    $scope.counter++;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('incrementedInController1', $scope.counter);
  }
  $scope.$on('incrementedInController2', function(event, newValueCounter) {
    $scope.counter = newValueCounter;
  });
}).controller('MainCtrl2', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.name2 = 'World2';
  $scope.counter = 0;
  $scope.incrementCounter = function() {
    $scope.counter++;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('incrementedInController2', $scope.counter);
  }
  $scope.$on('incrementedInController1', function(event, newValueCounter) {
    $scope.counter = newValueCounter;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$rootScope` which can be accessed from all controllers but it's not recommended because of debuging issues.

```
.controller('controllerA', controllerA);
  function controllerA($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.counter = 0;
}
.controller('controllerB', controllerA);
  function controllerB($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.counter = 1;
}
```

if you are using something common between all controllers it's recommended to use `Service` or `Factories` instead

here is a sample when to use it : 
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-service-factory-tutorial/